# Draw fixed line in real time graph jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, timeserieschart

So far I use TimeSeriesChart and DynamicTimeSeriesCollection to creat a chart like this:

[image: My current graph]

But the requirement is to let user click on the graph and define a "High" and "Low" boundary like the below picture:

[image: Requirement]

I've got this block of code to get the value when we click mouse on the graph:

```
public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
            Point2D p = chart.translateScreenToJava2D(cme.getTrigger().getPoint());
            Rectangle2D greyChartArea = chart.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea();
            double valueY = ((NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis()).java2DToValue(p.getY(), greyChartArea, plot.getRangeAxisEdge());
            double valueX = ((NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis()).java2DToValue(p.getX(), greyChartArea, plot.getDomainAxisEdge());
            System.out.println(valueY);
        }
```

The question is how to draw a fixed line when mouse is clicked with a real-time graph which has a dynamic x-axis? (Clicked points on the line should be movable and able to deleted)

Any pointers will be appreciated.

//**Updated**:

[image: Updated]

So far I can define my "High" and "Low" region by mouse but the problem is when the data comes in:

```
public void draw(Data data) {
    dataset.advanceTime();
    float[] info = new float[1];
    info[0] = data.getInfo();
    dataset.appendData(info);
}
```

the "High" and "Low" series will be disappeared or pushed away. Is there any way that can make "High" and "Low" fixed line?

Comment: You might be able to adapt the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38805252/230513).

Comment: How to plot a XYseriescollection in a timeserieschart though? @trashgod
Like the x-axis is a date axis, but the valueX from the code above is just a value of a clicked point (coordinate) and I want to plot a point(valueX, valueY)

Comment: A `DateAxis` displays `XYSeries` ordinates as seconds since the Java epoch, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20epoch).

Comment: @trashgod just updated. any solutions?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you added, compared to these [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20DynamicTimeSeriesCollection). Remember that `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` discards old data.

Comment: Because my first intention is to let users define a fixed High and Low boundary on the chart (the blue and green series), then the data (red series) will come in real time or loaded in (without affecting blue and green series). Is it possible with jFreechart?

Comment: I've not tried.