# Is it possible to perform an action event over a line?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a 2D line plot done with XY line chart using the `JFreeChart` library. Now, I would like to delete a series when the user clicks over that series line. Is it possible to do that? How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In outline,

- Add a [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) to determine the [`ChartEntity`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/entity/ChartEntity.html) that represents the selected series, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711095/230513); you can get the series index from the [`XYItemEntity`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/entity/XYItemEntity.html).
- Use one of the [`removeSeries()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeriesCollection.html#removeSeries-int-) methods of `XYSeriesCollection` to remove the chosen series.