# Make chips Selectable on mouse click event in wafermap jfree chart (javafx application)

Tags: javafx, jfreechart

I have created wafermap chart. I want to make chips(die) in wafer selectable on mouse click and insert labels as well lines from one chip to another. Anyone expert in jfree chart?

[wafermap chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0JHy.png)

Comment: What happens if you add a `ChartMouseListener`?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117760); a [tag:jfreechart] contributor observes that there is no entity support in the existing `WaferMapRenderer`.

Comment: @trashgod So how can I add mouse listner on every chip? which gives atleast me a label or some color changing of chip?

Comment: Look at how `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38711095/230513), implements entity support.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic pieces for a tooltip listener for wafer maps, which is a form of selecting the die.  Add the following to WaferMapPlot:

```
public String findChipAtPoint(double x, double y, Rectangle2D plotArea){
    double[] xValues = this.getChipXValues(plotArea, dataset.getMaxChipX()
         + 2, dataset.getChipSpace());
    double startX = xValues[1];
    double chipWidth = xValues[0];
    int ychips = this.dataset.getMaxChipY()+ 2;
    double[] yValues = this.getChipYValues(plotArea, ychips, 
         dataset.getChipSpace());
    double startY = yValues[1];
    double chipHeight = yValues[0];
    double chipSpace = dataset.getChipSpace();
    int chipX = (int)Math.floor((x - startX + chipWidth + chipSpace) / 
        (chipWidth + chipSpace));
    int chipY = (int)Math.floor((y - startY + chipHeight + chipSpace) / 
         (chipHeight + chipSpace));
    chipX = chipX - dataset.getXOffset() - 1;
    chipY = ychips - chipY - dataset.getYOffset() - 1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
    Number value = dataset.getChipValue(chipX, chipY);
    if (value instanceof Double)
        value = value.intValue();
    sb.append(chipX).append(",").append(chipY).append(") ").append(
       (value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then make a subclass of ChartPanel that will be the listener:

```
public class WaferMapChartPanel extends ChartPanel {

WaferMapPlot waferPlot = null;
WaferMapDataset dataSet = null;

public WaferMapChartPanel(JFreeChart chart){
    super(chart);
    waferPlot = (WaferMapPlot)chart.getPlot();
    if (waferPlot != null)
        dataSet = waferPlot.getDataset();
}

 /**
 * Returns a string for the tooltip.
 * @param e  the mouse event.
 * @return A tool tip or <code>null</code> if no tooltip is available.
 */
@Override
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
   if (waferPlot != null){
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof WaferMapChartPanel){
            WaferMapChartPanel chartSource= (WaferMapChartPanel)e.getSource();
            Rectangle2D plotArea = chartSource.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getPlotArea();
            Insets insets = this.getInsets();
            double x = (e.getX() - insets.left) / this.getScaleX();
            double y = (e.getY() - insets.top) / this.getScaleY();
            return waferPlot.findChipAtPoint(x, y, plotArea);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

This creates a tooltip of the die's x,y and bin or whatever value you are using instead of bin.