# Check if mouse is near a marker in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm creating a simple chart with [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), and i've added some instance of `IntervalMarker`:

```
private void addIntervalMarker(String name, double d1, double d2, Color c){
    IntervalMarker marker = new IntervalMarker(d1, d2);
    marker.setLabel(name);

    //Aesthetic changements...

    xylineChart.getXYPlot().addDomainMarker(marker, Layer.BACKGROUND);
}
```

Now I want to edit the original d1 and d2 param by dragging the interval marker. I know that I have to override the method `public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)`, but I don't know how to check if the mouse is near a side of the intervalMarker.

I can  check if the mouse y coordinate equals to the marker side y coordinate, but I don't want them to be the same. I would like to use something like:

```
final int DISTANCE= /* a number */ ... ;
double mY=/*mouseY*/ ... ;
double msY=/*markerSideY*/ ... ;
if( Math.abs(mY-msY)<DISTANCE )
    weCanChangeD1andD2();
```

But i don't want to use the chart x,y values, because i don't want to change DISTANCE with the zoom level!
Also, I want that when the mouse is near the marker, the pointer is attracted to the side of the marker.

How can i do it?

Comment: Why not `addChartMouseListener()` and listen for a `ChartEntity`?

Comment: I don't think `ChartEntity` includes markers, but these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20ChartMouseListener%20XYItemEntity) look at the `ChartEntity` subclass, `XYItemEntity`.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to _drag_ the marker. If you're using Swing, you can update the marker in the listener for a component like a spinner or a slider.

Comment: There's a discussion about marker dragging [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=117173) and a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38698176/230513).